# Should I use the indefinite/definite article before an alphabet letter?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

First, I don't know if these sentences are correct, but the question is should I use any kind of article before an alphabet letter in these sentences below?

> I got **an** E in math
>
> Please give me **a** G
>
> **The** A is the best grade

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your examples one at a time.

*I got an E in math/s* is correct. You would never say *I got E..." or "I got the E"

"Please give me a G" would be correct if there were blocks on a table, each with a letter of the alphabet, and you were asking someone for a block marked G.

If there were only a single *G block* you might ask for "the G". You might even just say *please give me G", meaning the block marked G.

*The A is the best grade" rings false. You could say either *A is the best grade" or "An A is the best grade".

This is very much as you could say either "Audi is my favourite car" (meaning the Audi marque) or *An Audi is my favourite car".

You would say *the Audi" only if you had been comparing Audi to some other marque, such as a BMW. Then you might say *the Audi is my preference* or *I prefer the Audi*.

Comment: "The best grade is an A" is another option.